# Custom Pop-up box doesnt close

Tags: jquery, css, popup, click, popupwindow

I have made a custom popup box on this website http://dutchinnovators.nl/dev/

By clicking on a hexagon, a hidden div structure is copied and prepended to #page and then faded in. This all works fine. However, the .bedrijf-popup doesn't want to close

It seems the Click action is not recognized or something, I've been trying to fix it for some time and searched the forums, but no luck.

Any help to close this popup would be appreciated!

**HTML**

```
<div class="bedrijf-popup">
    <div class="popup_black-bg"></div>
        <div class="popup_container">
            <div class="popup-close"></div>
            <content divs>                  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
  jQuery('.popup-close').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).bind('click', function(){    
      jQuery('#page > .bedrijf-popup .popup_black-bg').animate({'opacity': 0}, 500);
      jQuery('#page > .bedrijf-popup .popup_container').delay(500).animate({'opacity': 0}, 500);
      jQuery('#page > .bedrijf-popup').remove();
    });
 });
```

Comment: Are you sure? I just took your click handler and put it in the console. It works!

Comment: Yeah, thats weird. In the consule with "jQuery('.popup-close').click();" the popup-window closes. But not when i click with my mouse on the button. Any ideas?

Comment: put the jquery code in a $(document).ready(function(){...code here...});

Comment: I did that (http://i.imgur.com/dsnen3S.png) but physical mouseclick still doensnt work :S

Comment: You're using `jQuery('.popup-close').each`, so I wonder how many do you have in your page?

Comment: Remember to click the checkmark next to the answer that solved your problem. Also, feel free to upvote it if it "the answer was useful" :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that at the moment you're trying to bind the click handler, there is no `.popup-close` in the DOM since the whole element that contains it is being created only after clicking a hexagon. Bind though does not listen for later changes in the DOM.

So what you have to do is move the binding of your closing click handler from jQuery(document).ready() to the method that creates your `<div class="bedrijf-popup">`, **after** it has been added to the DOM.

That is also the reason why your click handler works if you call it in the console - obviously you're doing this in a setting where your popup is already there.

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

> Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery
>   object, so those elements **must** exist at the point the call to .bind()
>   occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event
>   delegation in [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Comment: This was happening, indeed. Changed around the DOM and now it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this alternative instead

```
 jQuery(document).bind("click", ".popup-close", function() {  
      jQuery('#page > .bedrijf-popup .popup_black-bg').animate({'opacity': 0}, 500);
      jQuery('#page > .bedrijf-popup .popup_container').delay(500).animate({'opacity': 0}, 500);
      jQuery('#page > .bedrijf-popup').remove();
 });
```

Or

```
 jQuery(document).bind("click", ".popup-close", function() {  
      jQuery(this).parents('.bedrijf-popup').find('.popup_black-bg').animate({'opacity': 0}, 500);
      jQuery(this).parents('.bedrijf-popup').find('.popup_container').delay(500).animate({'opacity': 0}, 500);
      jQuery(this).parents('.bedrijf-popup').remove();
 });
```

And since you're using jQuery 1.7.1, you can use 'on' instead of 'bind'

Comment: Thanks! ive put that code in the jQuery(document).ready(function($) and in the function firmaPopupInfo(); But no luck.. 
im lost, normally it works so easily..